# Determine two polynomials $p,q \neq 0 $ which are orthogonal in regards to an inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have shown that 
$$
\langle p,q \rangle = p(i) \cdot \overline{q(i)} + p(1) \cdot q(1) + \overline{p(i)} \cdot q(i)
$$
defines an inner product for the real vector space $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ which constains all real polynomials of order $\leq 2$.

I now have to determine two polynomials $p,q \neq 0$ which are orthogonal in regards to the above inner product but I do not know how to. Can you help me in the right direction? I know the definition of orthogonal in regards to vectors that
$$
a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + ... + a_nb_n = 0
$$
for given vectors $A$ and $B$ but I do not see how this helps me. Can you help me in the right direction?

Thanks

Regards

Mathias

Comment: No, the definition of orthogonal is $\langle a,b\rangle=0$. Orthogonality is determined by the inner product that you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

You can even take constant polynomials, namely $p(x)=1+\sqrt{3}i$ and $q(x)=1-\sqrt{3}i$. Then
$$
\langle p,q \rangle = p(i) \cdot \overline{q(i)} + p(1) \cdot q(1) + \overline{p(i)} \cdot q(i)=0.
$$
Indeed, writing $p=a+bi$ and $q=c+di$ we obtain
\begin{align}
 p(i) \cdot \overline{q(i)} & + p(1) \cdot q(1) + \overline{p(i)} \cdot q(i) =\\
(a+bi)(c-di) & +(a+bi)(c+di)+(a-bi)(c+di)=\\
3ac &+bd+(ad+bc)i.
\end{align}